# django and dataTables - speed up query and page display

Tags: django, datatables

I have a page in my app that lists all our client records - about a thousand total. The query is straight forward (two queries, actually) and look like this (one for commercial and one for  residential):

```
all_comm = System.objects.all().filter(isRessy=False)
all_ressy = System.objects.all().filter(isRessy=True)
```

In my template, I simply iterate over both queries displaying the information in a table. This code looks like this:

```
  <table style="width:100%;" class="field_container dt full-border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align=left width=200>Owner</th>
        <th align=center width=100>System ID</th>
        <th align=left>System Address</th>
        <th align=center width=200>Options</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      {% for System in all_ressy %}
      <tr onclick="window.location.href='{% url cpm.systems.views.system_overview System.systemID %}'">
        <td>{{ System.billingContact.lastName }}, {{ System.billingContact.firstName }}</td>
        <td align=center>{{ System.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ System.systemAddress }}, {{ System.systemCity }}</td>
        <td align=center>
          <a href="{% url cpm.work_orders.views.create_wo 'R' System.systemID %}?=next{% url cpm.systems.views.system_overview System.systemID %}">Create Service Call</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This code is identical for showing all the commercial records. If you'll notice that I have a class of `dt` listed in the table. That sets the table to be a `dataTable` table. As such, the rows get nice highlighting, the columns can be sorted, and there's a search box at the top of the table. All nice stuff.

The problem is that the page, as a whole, is a bit slow to load. It seems that half of the loading time is the raw displaying of data (fetching data then iterating over all the records generating the basic `HTML` table). The second half of the loading time (or at least a decent chunk of the time) looks to be devoted to converting the regular table into a `dataTable`.

I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to speed this whole process up. I've tried using pagination on the `dataTable` but that seems to be useless since all the records are loaded anyway, just hidden across multiple `dataTable` pages. Real pagination for the whole page isn't really possible given the nature of the app. I feel like the queries aren't going to get any faster so there's got to be optimization or some trick to make this page load faster.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for the help

***Edit*** I'm referring to this dataTable plugin: http://datatables.net/index

Comment: you need to use datatable ajax paginatio

Comment: @Garfonzo Which approach have you used in the end to speed up page loading?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using ajax to load the data directly into the `DataTable` It would remove the HTML rendering step.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html (I assume this is the datatables you are talking about...)

Comment: ya, perhaps I should update my question to indicate which 'dataTables' I'm talking about... So, with the method you are suggesting, it looks like it will only load 10 (or some quantity) of records per page. As such, using pagination would actually be faster since it's loading fewer pages.

Comment: If you prepare appriopriate server-side method for collect parameters and create JSON, you can use `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` datatables parameters for populate only part of data for one paginated page.